# Python random URL choice

Tags: python

I am trying to select a random URL from this list using choice, but its not working. Here is my code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, sys
num = sys.argv[1]
print 'Started'
phones = [
'http://1.1.1.6/index.htm,'
'http://1.1.1.5/index.htm,'
'http://1.1.1.4/index.htm,'
'http://1.1.1.3/index.htm,'
'http://1.1.1.2/index.htm,'
'http://1.1.1.1/index.htm'
]
from random import choice
data = urllib.urlencode({"NUMBER":num, "DIAL":"Dial", "active_line":1})
while 1:
    for phone in phones:

                         urllib2.urlopen(choice(phone),data) # make call
                         urllib2.urlopen(choice(phone)+"?dialeddel=0") # clear
logs
```

This is the error I get

```
File "p.py", line 21, in ?
    urllib2.urlopen(choice(phone),data) # make call
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 130, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 350, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 233, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: 5
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: choice('hello') -> one letter ... choice(phone) will only return one letter of the url

Answer (score 4):

Your commas are inside of your strings. As a result, your phones variable is a list of a single large string. Your random choice is giving you a single character from that string. Change it to this:

```
phones = [
    'http://1.1.1.6/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.5/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.4/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.3/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.2/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.1/index.htm',
]
```

Also you should not iterate over phones but simply select a phone using `random.choice(phones)`.

Also you're selecting a different random phone for your two URL calls, which I'm guessing isn't what you want. Here's a complete, refactored code.

```
import urllib, urllib2, sys, random

phones = [
    'http://1.1.1.6/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.5/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.4/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.3/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.2/index.htm',
    'http://1.1.1.1/index.htm',
]

num = sys.argv[1]
data = urllib.urlencode({"NUMBER": num, "DIAL": "Dial", "active_line": 1})
while 1:
    phone = random.choice(phones)
    urllib2.urlopen(phone, data) # make call
    urllib2.urlopen(phone + "?dialeddel=0") # clear logs
```

Comment: I have used this, and it successfully works the first time using a random, but after that, the phones don't call anymore. With the old code, it would keep calling until I stopped it, but with only the first phone in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get a random index

```
import random
phones = [
'http://1.1.1.6/index.htm',
'http://1.1.1.5/index.htm',
'http://1.1.1.4/index.htm',
'http://1.1.1.3/index.htm',
'http://1.1.1.2/index.htm',
'http://1.1.1.1/index.htm',
]

index random.randrange(0, len(phones)-1)
phones[index]
```